# Cant debug build app on android 4.4.2 but it works on android 6.0.1

Tags: android, exception, proguard

The error I get is:(this is a large project)

```
Note: there were 10 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 239 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 27 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)

Warning: there were 2292 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 241 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)

Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

There´s a big log output from Gradle and I know I must clean up the proguard-rules.pro eventually but why does it work on android 6.0.1 and not on android 4.4.2. The log end with "Build failed with an exception" and I try to "Run with --stacktrace " but cant see the exception

Comment: What do you mean by `work on android 6.0.1 and not on android 4.4.2`? If your code requires SDK 23 to compile and you set `compileSdkVersion` to something lower there will be classes missing. The question is, why do you lower `compileSdkVersion`? Perhaps you meant to change `targetSdkVersion` or `minSdkVersion` instead.

Comment: My app build gradle have ` compileSdkVersion 26 ,  buildToolsVersion "25.0.3" , minSdkVersion 16 ,   targetSdkVersion 26 `

Comment: I can run the app on android 6.0.1 Marshmallow api 23 but not on 4.4.2.

Comment: It may be because you have too many method references in your project and Android 4 can't run such apps out-of-box. You could [enable multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) but you should rather start optimizing those proguard rules now, since that's better for performace.

Comment: Thanks Yea I will optimize of course. About multidex I dont see any build error that indicates my app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture and it does run on api 23

Comment: Do you have some more suggestions?

Comment: I use the (real device) 4.4.2 Galaxy tab 3 to calibrate and test layout xml and suddenly this happened. This last week I plugged in a custom library like `include ':app', 'emoji-keyboard-erikswed'
project(':emoji-keyboard-erikswed').projectDir = new File('D:/git/emoji-keyboard-erikswed/emoji-library')` but I cant see any trouble with this and the Multidex should alarm about reached the limit of the Android build architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
The reason was in app build gradle I was using play-services 11.4.0 and firebase 11.4.2. 
Somehow I missed syncing them to use the same version..